# How to add new button in tiny_mce from magento 2 module?

Tags: plugins, module, magento2, tinymce-4

I have already made a wordpress plugin for tiny_mce editor via add_filter() function.
I included the js file of tiny_mce plugin. It works properly. 
Now when same thing I am willing to develop for magento 2. I have create basic hello_world module with this tutorial:
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/
Now from this module how I add my custom button in tiny_mce editor.

Advance thanks for reply.....

Comment: I am facing the same error, have you got solution for this? Please share it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've wrote a [blog post](https://blog.hauri.me/how-to-add-a-tinymce-plugin-to-the-magento2-wysiwyg-editor.html) about how to add a TinyMCE pluing to the Magento WYSIWYG Editor.

I've also created a [demo module](https://github.com/mhauri/magento2-demo-tinymce-plugin) which should give you a direction how to do it for yourself.

Comment: I mixed this module with Magento's Variable module and got a pretty modal appearing to chose between different layouts to insert into the wysiwyg editor. Thanks !

Comment: Have to always this module ?, I want the same as @Marcel Hauri but when I click on that button, he open first some modal popup then I shoose wich template I want to add then onClick he add me the content of the selected template. have you an idea for this ?

Comment: @Cladiuss, anything you want to share? :)